# Qt AbstractItemModel removeRows and delete causes core

Tags: c++, qt

I have the following to insert nodes:

```
  layoutAboutToBeChanged();
  beginInsertRows(createIndex(p_parent->row(), 0, p_parent), start, end);
  TreeNode* p_node = new TreeNode(p_parent, p_data);
  p_parent->appendChild(start, p_node);
  endInsertRows();
  layoutChanged();
```

And to remove rows:

```
  layoutAboutToBeChanged();
  beginRemoveRows(createIndex(p_parent->row(), 0, p_parent), row, row);
  p_parent->removeChildren(row, row+1, this);
  endRemoveRows();
  layoutChanged();
```

When `removeChildren` is called, for each node that is removed the following is done:

```
 changePersistentIndex(createIndex(p_node->row(), 0, p_node), QModelIndex());
 delete p_node;
```

It works. I can add nodes and remove nodes.

**Terminology NOTE**: I'm using `nodes` and `rows` interchangeably. Sorry for any confusion.

What doesn't work:

1. If a new row is inserted in front of a selected node. The newly
   inserted node becomes selected. [This is not what I expect of want.]
2. If a row is selected and then later deleted, immediate core dump.
3. If mouse over a row that is deleted, immediate core dump.

If I don't delete `p_node`. Everything runs fine. But obviously that creates a memory leak.
What am I doing wrong?

For reference I'm using QT 5.0.2 on 64 bit Linux.

Comment: Run it under debugger and view the stack trace of error.

Comment: @Riateche I have done that. The stacktrace shows it crashing when the size() is called on QList which is inside the TreeNode. This call to size() is made from QTree trying to paint itself and accessing the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do append and remove children methods update the rowCount?

It seems to be the problem.

Check how is done in [QStandardItemModel](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/85f42777111060037476895ed08ded513d44a048/src/gui/itemviews/qstandarditemmodel.cpp#line398)

Updating rowcount should solve the 3 points without having to update the persistent indexes:

1. If rowcount is not updated, is normal that selected item changes to the inserted before, its where the index is pointing.
2. & 3. Indexes are pointing to a deleted item.

Answer (score 1):

To fix crashes you should use [deleteLater](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#deleteLater) instead of delete, so your view won't die trying to access invalid objects.

Selected item seems a index problem. Looks like it's missing a notification to view.

Comment: TreeNode is not a QT Object. It receives no signals.

Answer (score 0):

to point 1: maybe

```
model->blockSignals(true);
...
model->blockSignals(false);
```

will fix that selection behaviour.

i guess selected indexes/rows will have some functions called from the framework. so if they are deleted, they cause the crash. if you want to delete them, set the selection to another row/index and it should run fine ... '

if you mouse over a deleted row' ... if the row should be just empty, why not set the text empty?

Comment: I mean if I have my mouse over a row as it is being deleted.